# NullPointerException getText()/Popup/EditText Android

Tags: null, popup, nullpointerexception, gettext

When I call:

```
channel_name  = textinput.getText().toString();
```

I get a NullPointerException.
I think my problem is in that Code line:

```
final EditText textinput = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.popup_plaintext);
```

But I just can't find the mistake.
I also used the search, but I still don't get it.
I hope someone can help me here.

Here u can watch my full code:

```
package de.project.ibob;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnLongClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.Switch;


public class ModuleActivity extends Activity{

//Data
    int a = 16;
    int b = 6;
    byte[][] buffer = new byte[a][b];
    public int LongClickID;
    public String channel_name;

//Debugging
    private static final String TAG = "ModuleActivity";
    private static final boolean D = true;

//Layout
    private PopupWindow pwindo;
    private RadioGroup mradiogroup;
    private RadioButton mradiobutton[] = new RadioButton[7];
    private Switch mswitch[] = new Switch[33];
    private Button buttonClosePopup;
    public Switch textoutput;

    private void SavePreferences() {

        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("Channels", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

//Buttons
        for(int i = 1; i < 7; i++) {

            editor.putBoolean("radio" + i, mradiobutton[i].isChecked());

        }//for

        for(int i = 1; i < 33; i++) {

            editor.putBoolean("switch" + i, mswitch[i].isChecked());

        }//for

        editor.commit();

    }//SafePreferences

    private void LoadPreferences() {

        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("Channels", 0);
//       
//Buttons
        for(int i = 1; i < 7; i++) {

            mradiobutton[i].setChecked(settings.getBoolean("radio" + i, false));

        }//for

        for(int i = 1; i < 33; i++) {

            mswitch[i].setChecked(settings.getBoolean("switch" + i, false));

        }//for

    }//LoadPreferences

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if(D) Log.e(TAG, "+++ ON CREATE +++");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

//Layout
        setContentView(R.layout.modules);

//RadioGroup
        mradiogroup = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radio_group_modules);

//RadioButtons (i = 1 because of radiobutton_modules_module ID starts at 1! ==> i <7 NOT 6!) 
        for(int i = 1; i < 7; i++) {

            String RadioID = "radiobutton_modules_module" + i;
            int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(RadioID, "id", "de.project.ibob");
            mradiobutton[i] = ((RadioButton)findViewById(resID));
            if(D) Log.e(TAG, "+++ SetRadioButton +++" + i);

        }//for

//Switches  (i = 1 because of Switch ID starts at 1! ==> i <33 NOT 32!)     
        for(int i = 1; i < 33; i++) {

            String SwitchID = "Switch" + i;
            int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(SwitchID, "id", "de.project.ibob");
            mswitch[i] = ((Switch)findViewById(resID));
            mswitch[i].setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener(){

                @Override
                   public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                    if(D) Log.e(TAG, "+++ LongClick +++" + v.getId());

                    LongClickID = v.getId();
                    initiatePopupWindow();

                    return true;
                   }
            });
            if(D) Log.e(TAG, "+++ Switch +++" + i);

        }//for

//Buttons Listener
        mradiogroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int mradiogroup) {

            for(int i = 1; i < 7; i++) {

                if(mradiobutton[i].isChecked() == true) {
                    if(D) Log.e(TAG, "+++ RadioButton selected +++");


//Identifier (MODUL - Read/Write - Channel) all 16 Messages get the same ModulID
                    for(a = 0; a < 15; a++) {

                        if(i == 1)buffer[a][0] = 0x01;
                        if(i == 2)buffer[a][1] = 0x02;
                        if(i == 3)buffer[a][2] = 0x03;
                        if(i == 4)buffer[a][3] = 0x04;
                        if(i == 5)buffer[a][4] = 0x05;
                        if(i == 6)buffer[a][5] = 0x06;



                        }//for

                    if(D) Log.e(TAG, "ID Byte:" + i + " selected");

                    }//if
                }//for
            }//onCheckedChanged 
        });//setOnCheckedChangedListener

//Functions
            LoadPreferences();

    }//onCreate

   @Override 
    public void onBackPressed() {

        SavePreferences();
        super.onBackPressed();

        if(D) Log.e(TAG, "+++ onBackPressed +++");



    }//onBackPressed

  public void initiatePopupWindow() {

     try{
       LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
               ModuleActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup,
               (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.popup_element));

       pwindo = new PopupWindow(layout,600,250,true);
       pwindo.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER,0,0);

       buttonClosePopup = (Button)layout.findViewById(R.id.button_modules_popup_setText);
       buttonClosePopup.setOnClickListener(cancel_button_click_listener);

     }//try

     catch(Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
   }


   public OnClickListener cancel_button_click_listener = new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View cancel_button_click_listener){

            final EditText textinput = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.popup_plaintext);
            channel_name  = textinput.getText().toString();
            textoutput = (Switch)findViewById(LongClickID);
            textoutput.setText(channel_name);
            pwindo.dismiss();
    }
   };
   }
```

stacktrace:

```
01-26 00:13:58.071: E/AndroidRuntime(15877): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-26 00:13:58.071: E/AndroidRuntime(15877): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-26 00:13:58.071: E/AndroidRuntime(15877):    at de.project.ibob.ModuleActivity$1.onClick(ModuleActivity.java:205)
01-26 00:13:58.071: E/AndroidRuntime(15877):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4232)
01-26 00:13:58.071: E/AndroidRuntime(15877):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17318)
01-26 00:13:58.071: E/AndroidRuntime(15877):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
01-26 00:13:58.071: E/AndroidRuntime(15877):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-26 00:13:58.071: E/AndroidRuntime(15877):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-26 00:13:58.071: E/AndroidRuntime(15877):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
01-26 00:13:58.071: E/AndroidRuntime(15877):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-26 00:13:58.071: E/AndroidRuntime(15877):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-26 00:13:58.071: E/AndroidRuntime(15877):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
01-26 00:13:58.071: E/AndroidRuntime(15877):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
01-26 00:13:58.071: E/AndroidRuntime(15877):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And here you can see my layout xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/popup_element"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#444444" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/popup_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="@string/set_name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_modules_popup_setText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/popup_plaintext"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
        android:text="@string/set_channelname"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/popup_plaintext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/popup_text"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thank you

Comment: Is textinput initialized with any content, when you look at it in the debugger?

Comment: No it says textinput = null, so there is no content. But I write a text in the PlainText. So where could my mistake be?

Comment: So that's the reason for the NPE. As I'm not aware of the Android API I can only guess, but either findViewById returns null for some reason or the cast to EditText does not work. Check also, if there are any compiler warnings, which might be suspicious.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you use final on textinput?

Comment: So I got the mistake. For any reason I was not able to call findViewById in onClick. When I moved it to onCreate it worked. Also I had to change it to  textinput = (EditText)layout.findViewById(R.id.popup_plaintext);

Answer (score 0):

Your missing an identifier on your findView, I fixed a similar NPE by adding the popup view to the findViewById(). This should do the trick if I have your view right
`final EditText textinput = (EditText)layout.findViewById(R.id.popup_plaintext);`